# Getting error while i am trying to convert data type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert the data type for TotalCharges to float
but it is throwing me error

churn['TotalCharges']=churn['TotalCharges'].astype(float)

I am trying to convert the data type for TotalCharges to float
but it is throwing me the error

ValueError: could not convert string to float:' '

Comment: paste your input data.

Comment: its like 28.9 1889.4 and so on

Comment: try with this-> pd.to_numeric(df['DataFrame Column'],errors='coerce')